# How to check the GPU temperature without installing vcgencmd

Tags: gpu

I would like to check the GPU temperature in my Ubuntu machine. I have searched online where they have mentioned using vcgencmd.
But instead of using vcgencmd or installing any plugins is there a way to find the GPU temperature

Comment: There's `lm_sensors` which would probably need to be installed but can be installed with `sudo apt install lm_sensors` and then run with a simple `sensors` command. I also dug up [a link](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/check-gpu-temperature-on-linux/). I'm not sure what you mean by 'plugins' in this particular context, but you will most likely need to install an application to do so.

Comment: there is also psensor - https://linuxmasterclub.com/psensor/ - and a vitals gnome extension in tweaks - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

Comment: @KGIII To check the CPU temperature we can use the following command in our terminal  `cd /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone` once navigated we can print the temperature using `cat temp` which would print the CPU temperature. Similarly is there an option to view GPU temperature without any external plugins